# Weak product of Eilemberg MacLane spaces

Tags: algebraic-topology, cw-complexes, eilenberg-maclane-spaces

I'm studying some homotopy theory of topological monoids from the book [Algebraic Topology from a Homotopical Viewpoint](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387954509).
I'm trying to understand the corollary below.

[image]
[image]

I'm stuck on the first claim of the proof. I think that the assertion should follow by proving that weak products of Eilemberg MacLane spaces (more generally CW-complexes) is a CW-complex. Any help?

Comment: The topology is the colimit of the finite products and finite products of CW complexes are CW complexes.

Comment: Yes but finite product in the CW category. Do you think that the author takes product in this category?

Comment: The finite CW product is weakly equivalent to the regular product and the CW product is a CW complex, so I think yes. It is true that they are not clear on this point. I should mention that if you work in a convenient category of topological spaces, the categorical product of CW complexes is always a CW complex (it just doesn't necessarily have the product topology).